# App rejected due to missing usage descriptions (Xcode8)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios10, xcode8

So I got this mail today saying that the latest build of my app was rejected by iTunes Connect due to some missing usage descriptions. To be exact:

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSContactsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMotionUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

I figured out that these have become mandatory with iOS 10, but the only problem is that my app is not requesting permission to access any of these.. I thought the description only was mandatory if you actually requested a permission?

Is it because one of my dependencies (Cocoapods) might contain some code to request these permissions? Or are these descriptions mandatory even if I never request to see the users calendar, contacts, etc?

Comment: From my experience - these are necessary only if you are requesting the permissions. So maybe some dependency is doing this for you. Also ALL of these permissions smell fishy especially if your app is a simple todo list. Maybe some dependency is going phishing?

Comment: Could you post your `PodFile` and the list of the libraries you use (if you use some outside cocoapods) ?

Comment: It was https://github.com/nickoneill/PermissionScope/ .. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ُhis explained and show usage : https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html

Comment: i have exactly same problem and i guess it is caused by: pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The descriptions are mandatory for any content you or any frameworks you link against attempt to access. The errors are generated upon an attempt to access the content if a usage description was not supplied, so if you're getting those errors your app must be requesting them. You should discover why your app or its frameworks require these and add appropriate usage descriptions to your app's info.plist.

Or more ideally, if you don't need access, see if there's a way to not request it (or use frameworks that do unnecessarily).

Comment: I couldn't for the life of me imagine that I would add a library requesting all these permissions. But it was so obvious when I found it: https://github.com/nickoneill/PermissionScope/

Comment: Yeah a framework like that might not be a great idea because it causes your app to declare way more permissions than it needs.

Comment: @KimAMartinsen What the hell. Your question saved me and the comment right here. Is it some kind of bug with PermissionScope? I really need it but it is impossible to use if I get errors like this :D

Comment: I guess this is more of a feature then a bug.. iTunes Connect detects that somewhere in your app, someone might request permissions. In that case you have to fill in usage descriptions for all of these, in case you might actually invoke some of the code in permissionscope. I like the framework as well and I'm not ready to replace it. So i filled in some bogus text, and the app was approved. I've submitted it in to the AppStore, so hopefully it will be ok :-)

Comment: Need a way to detect which framework is requesting those permission?

Comment: Neobie - did you find how you can detect the frameworks requesting the permissions?

Comment: @neobie, there is a way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676740/what-makes-nscalendarsusagedescription-required - along with this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1937/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017549

Comment: @nitesh, there is a way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676740/what-makes-nscalendarsusagedescription-required - along with this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1937/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017549

Answer (score 142):

**iOS 10** must add permission in **info.plist** just review this [BLOG :- settings-in-ios-10](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/) you get all idea.

**Add permission** in **info.plist** file base on your **error** log.

> **Note:** Write proper reason for permission in string value otherwise apple reject app again.

**NSCameraUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSContactsUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSMicrophoneUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSMotionUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) motion use.</string>
```

**NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSLocationUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSRemindersUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSSiriUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSVideoSubscriberAccountUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSVideoSubscriberAccountUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

**NSCalendarsUsageDescription**

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>You have to describe the real usage for a human.</string>
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be "${PRODUCT_NAME}" instead of "$(PRODUCT_NAME)"? "{}" instead of "()".

Comment: @backslash-f, Please check existing plist file in new project and it should be `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`. You can see default property like `Bundle name` in plist file.

Comment: Please note a generic description like this will no longer get you through the app store approval. We were just dinged twice for similar descriptions. You have to describe the real usage for a human

Answer (score 9):

You can add in your info.plist like :

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Explain the reasons for accessing...</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Explain the reasons for accessing...</string>
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Explain the reasons for accessing...</string>
```

etc.

Hope will help someone...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, and it appears that if any framework you link against *has code that asks this permission* (even if your app never requests them), the usage descriptions are necessary. But according to my test, if you don't request them, they won't appear in the permissions list of your app.

Answer (score 3):

**Calendar :**
Key      :  Privacy - Calendars Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) calendar events

**Reminder :**
Key      :   Privacy - Reminders Usage Description
Value  :   $(PRODUCT_NAME) reminder use

**Contact** :
Key       :   Privacy - Contacts Usage Description
Value    :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) contact use

**Photo :**
Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use

**Bluetooth Sharing :**
Key       :  Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) Bluetooth Peripheral use

**Microphone :**
Key        :  Privacy - Microphone Usage Description
Value    :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) microphone use

**Camera :**
Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use

**Location :**
Key      :  Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) location use

Key       :  Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) location use

**Heath :**
Key      :  Privacy - Health Share Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) heath share use

Key      :  Privacy - Health Update Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) heath update use

**HomeKit :**
Key      :  Privacy - HomeKit Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) home kit use

**Media Library :**
Key      :  Privacy - Media Library Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) media library use

**Motion :**
Key      :  Privacy - Motion Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) motion use

**Speech Recognition :**
Key      :  Privacy - Speech Recognition Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) speech use

**SiriKit  :** 
Key      :  Privacy - Siri Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) siri use

**TV Provider :** 
Key      :  Privacy - TV Provider Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) tvProvider use

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering why all of a sudden your app now has all these permission settings in the first place it could be because of CocoaPods or Carthage - they put in hooks to all of these permissions. I just upgraded my app to use cordova-plugin-firebasex which has an extensive Cocoapods (and dependencies) installation. You can turn these permissions off BEFORE you install cocoapods into your project by putting a PermissionsConfiguration.xcconfig in the root of your project - you can read more about this here: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Permission#installation

This all surprised me when the new version of my app was rejected with 7 permissions key/string missing from Info.plist file. I then had to dig into my project to find what was causing this since my app doesn't need or use any of these permissions (never has).

It may exist but at the moment I can't find a way to remove permissions after pods integration...going to have to dig around on how to do this without starting my project over.