# Declaring usage access to Microphone for privacy settings in info.plist iOS 10

Tags: ios10, info-plist

In my project i am using a hardware that uses the headphone jack to connect to the device and used to swipe card. Do i need to declare the usage access for microphone in info.plist?

My problem is few of my users reporting that the application crashes after login. from the below crash log i suspect that the related to an issue in accessing the privacy settings(i am not sure though). Please check the crash log as well and guide me on how to solve this issue.

```
#9. Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18ae60d74 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18ae5d480 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18ae5d4c8 system_set_sfi_window + 10
3  TCC                            0x18e0a0328 __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_2.80 + 258
4  TCC                            0x18e0a0224 __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 702
5  TCC                            0x18e0a3330 __tccd_send_block_invoke + 348
6  libxpc.dylib                   0x18af6601c _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 80
7  libxpc.dylib                   0x18af65f8c _xpc_connection_call_reply + 40
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18ad1d1c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18ad2bab4 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 732
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18ad2d38c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18ad2d0ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18af262b8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18af25da4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols` permission for user external hardware.

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
    <array>
        <string>PROTOCOL_NAME_HERE</string>
    </array>
```

`PROTOCOL_NAME_HERE` is bundle identifier of your protocol/external accessory.

And you have to add `ExternalAccessory.framework` in your project (Click on your project in the Project Navigator on the left side. In General go to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". Click on the + button).

Comment: why should i import <ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h> and in which file i should import

Comment: I have included a SDK provided by the hardware company to handle hardware detection and other things

Comment: are you using cocoapods to inclue library/sdk ?

Comment: No i am not using cocoapods to include the library.

Comment: ExternalAccessory framework is use to communicate between hardware andiOS.

Comment: can you please tell that which SDK you are using?

Comment: Unimag SDK provided by ID TECH

Comment: you have to add `ExternalAccessory.framework` in Linked Frameworks and Library in you project

Comment: its already added. please let me update my question to explain my problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133530/discussion-between-prabhu-and-jayesh-thanki).

Comment: UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols has been added to the plist as well.

Comment: you can add permission as you want. refer this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39717266/2284065

Comment: simply add missing permission key in info.plist file.