# Xcode and iOS Simulator app has no connection

Tags: xcode, ionic2, ios-simulator

I have developed an app using `Ionic2`. I can run it in a browser and an Android Emulator with no problems. I have now deployed it to `iOS Simulator` (`Xcode`), and I get the following two issues (I am not sure if they are related).

1. `iOS Simulator` has an internet connection, because when I access Safari in the Simulator, it can see the internet. However, my app that needs to access some RESTful Services (hosted on `AWS`) just hangs when doing so. It is as if the app cannot access the internet.

I do get the following in the log:

> 2017-02-23 16:33:37.356 theWhoZoo[11863:1077448] Resetting plugins due
>   to page load. 2017-02-23 16:33:39.236 theWhoZoo[11863:1077448] DEVICE
>   READY FIRED AFTER 1420 ms 2017-02-23 16:33:39.275
>   theWhoZoo[11863:1077448] This app has attempted to access
>   privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's
>   Info.plist must contain an NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key
>   with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data

2. When I try use `FireBase` login, I get the following error:

> This operation is not supported in the environment this application is
>   running on. "location.protocol" must be http or https and web storage
>   must be enabled.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Question 1 by looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415895/app-rejected-due-to-missing-usage-descriptions-xcode8). Needed to add the following line to the `...info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) location use.</string>
```

Question 2 still unanswered.