# App Rejected - Missing info.Plist key

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Trying to deploy my first app to the App Store but got some errors.

My app was rejected from the App Store due to the following:

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSContactsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

[My info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHt7H.png)

Could someone give me more info? How to add these keys?

Pretty new to Swift and Xcode, so this may be a super simple fix!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App rejected due to missing usage descriptions (Xcode8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415895/app-rejected-due-to-missing-usage-descriptions-xcode8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are specific keys you need to add in order to use access certain features. You have to add a description to explain to the user why you need to access these features. The ones you need to add (as per your question), are below. Once you include the keys, you enter the description as the value.

- Privacy - Contacts Usage Description
- Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
- Privacy - Microphone Usage Description
- Privacy - Camera Usage Description

  [image: info.plist screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! That worked, it was a really simple fix. Got my app on TestFlight now. Really appreciate the help