# Apple rejected app with NSCameraUsageDescription key missing issue without my app using Camera

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I had developed an iOS app that i had uploaded many times without any issues after iOS 10 and was available on app store .But now i had requirement to integrate crash logging so I integrated Fabric and Crashlytics in my app but once i added pods for these App store is rejecting my binary saying

Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

NSCameraUsageDescription is used when we use Camera feature in the app but my app doesn't have any one but still apple is giving above issue.

Does Fabric or Crashlytics use Camera feature? Because once i integrated that I'm getting above issue. If yes why it uses so that i can put value for NSCameraUsageDescription key in my plist.

Other pods i'm using are SwiftHTTP, SwiftyJSON, FontAwesome.swift, MBCalendarKit, TestFairy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415895/app-rejected-due-to-missing-usage-descriptions-xcode8/39415968 This answer helps you to solve this. Prefer answer of @Matthew Seaman. I had same problem and one of my framework uses camera not my app so it required to add camera permission in info.plist.

Comment: Do you have it ticked int he capabilities of the app?