# React Native navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition how to customize the Alert Text Message

Tags: ios, react-native, location, app-store, user-permissions

In React Native we have this function to access the Device's Location:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
```

As we see in this sample code, it receives a onSuccess and onFail functions, and also an object as third parameter where you can customize *enableHighAccuracy*, *timeout* and *maximumAge*.

Then when you call this, the first time it shows a Modal, requesting the user's permission to access his location. 
 So my question is:

**How can I customize the text displayed in that Modal alert?**

[image]

Now Apple introduced some guiadance that requires to mention what the permission is being requested for, but I dont see a way to customize tha text message programatically.

I am stuck, and my app is being rejected many times because of this. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open your react native ios project with `Xcode`
2. Select `info` tab
3. Find `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` key (Example Privacy - Camera Usage Description)
4. Edit value to describe why you request to access this
   [image]
5. When app show popup request will show description that you fill
   [image]

More info check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39717266/1754750)

Comment: Marked as the RIGHT answer. Thanks a lot man. You saved my app. :-)